# C++ endl() without std:: prefix or using statement

Tags: c++

Why does this use of `endl()` without a namespace qualifier compile?  I've tried it on multiple compilers, searched through several pages of search here for "endl without std::", and I'm stumped as to why it's not even a warning.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    endl(std::cout << "hello weirdness");
    return 0;
}
```

This is distilled from a bit of deliberately obfuscated code found at another site, and is *not* something I'd use in a real program.  I just don't see why it doesn't complain that `endl` isn't defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::endl` is a function template with the following signature:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& endl(std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os);
```

When the argument has type `std::ostream`, [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) occurs and the function name `endl` is searched for in the namespace `std`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what's happening all right.  Thanks!  I wonder what problem this solved.  It (ADL) seems to have more "principle of greatest astonishment" potential than any use I can imagine for it.

Comment: @MikeHousky: ADL also applies to `operator <<` in `std::cout << "Hi"`, you don't have to write `std::operator << (std::cout, "Hi")`.